# Is it possible to compile an external git repository that doesn't contain Cargo.toml with Cargo?

Tags: git, dependencies, rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to clone the [SFML github repo](https://github.com/SFML/SFML) in my local project directory and build it using the build.rs Cargo solution and I get this error:

> Could not find Cargo.toml

I didn't find any way to fetch a repo that doesn't contain a Cargo.toml config file from my own Cargo.toml config!

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve). In this case, a minimized version of your `Cargo.toml` and your `build.rs` would be a good start. As currently stated, your question doesn't make sense — you can't add non-Rust code as a Cargo dependency.

Comment: Judging from the code, it uses CMake to build. Cargo-ifying may either be trivial or serious work. The only way to know is to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SFML is not a Rust project, you of course cannot directly build it with `cargo`. However within `build.rs`, you can easily [run](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) the respective CMake commands to perform the build. Afterwards, you probably want to add something to the linker search path – something along these lines:

```
// build.rs
println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/search/path/to/add");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=sfml");
```